# поиск по нескольким условиям или по одному

Tags: php

Такой вопрос. Есть база данных mysql. В ней содержатся поля: дата загрузки файла, дата подписания файла, имя чела, который загрузил, имя чела который подписал документ, тип документа и номер документа. Есть форма с пятью соответствующими бд полями. Надо сделать что бы поиск осуществлялся в пределах этих 5 полей с возможностью поиска по нескольким или одному критерию.

Пробовал так. Указание в не требующихся полях значение, равное тому которое находится в поле. То есть, значение поля равное самому себе. Читал, что есть такой способ. Но при выборке неуказанное поле заключается в кавычки. Например `... WHERE users = 'users'...` Так поиск вообще не дает результатов.

Задаю одно из полей таким образом. Таких несколько. Делаю это в файле, отображающем главную страницу

```
<?php
    $userupquery = "SELECT DISTINCT userup FROM uploads ORDER BY userup"; //ограничение повторяющихся строк DISTINCT
    $userupresult = mysqli_query($con, $userupquery) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    echo "<select name='search_userup'><option></option>";
    while ($useruprow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userupresult)){
    echo"<option>".$useruprow['userup']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Далее с помощью include подключаю другой файл, содержащий

```
if(isset($_POST['search_userup'])){
    $search_userup = trim($_POST['search_userup']);
}{$search_type = 'userup';}
```

и далее формирую запрос

```
if(isset($_POST['search_userup']) or isset($_POST['search_usersig_short']) or isset($_POST['search_type']) or isset($_POST['search_dateup']) or isset($_POST['search_datesig'])//or isset($_POST['search_number']) 
){
    $searchquery = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE userup='$search_userup' AND usersig_short='$search_usersig_short' AND type='$search_type' AND dateup='$search_dateup' AND datesig='$search_datesig'";
}else{
    $searchquery = "SELECT * FROM uploads ORDER BY dateup DESC LIMIT 0, 10"; // стандартное отображение без поиска
}
```

Comment: Добавьте то, что пытались сами сделать и тогда Вам обязательно помогут. Покажите, что Вы действительно стремитесь разобраться в вопросе, а не просто закидываете сюда задачу. За Вас никто с нуля всё делать не будет. Увы.

Comment: Ты не пробовал указывать в запросе только нужные поля?

Comment: @uberiruki Добавьте Ваш код и разметку. Как делаете запрос в БД, через pdo или mysqli? Запрос должен быть примерно такой -  `$query = "SELECT * FROM НазваниеТаблицы WHERE users ='$users'";` если одно поле и `$query = "SELECT * FROM НазваниеТаблицы WHERE (users='$users') AND (name='$name')";` если несколько полей. Где `$users` и `$name` - Ваши параметры.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос пример кода. Необходим поиск именно по этим параметром. Либо по одному или нескольким, так как пользователи точно не знают один из параметров. Поэтому указывают только те, что им известны, что бы найти файл

Comment: Лучше такие запросы делать через библиотеку FluentPDO или аналогичные.